# How convert a character to integer

Tags: c++

Suppose if I have a character let's say char a ='9' and I need to convert it into interger value 9 .How can I do that?.I have tried using inbuilt function atoi().But it is giving error  saying you can only pass constant pointer as a arugument.

Comment: `'90'` is not a valid `char`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple. just subtract '0' from that character.

```
char a = '9';
int value = a - '0'; // value = 9.
```

because ascii value of '9' is 57 and '0' is 48.

So actually it becomes

int value = 57 - 48;

That is value = 9.

Comment: It’s not just because ASCII. The C and C++ language definitions require that the encodings for the characters `’0’ .. ‘9’` be contiguous and increasing. So `ch - ‘0’` works for **every** character encoding.